# Python sorted function doesn't do anything

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like `a = {'10': 2.0, '3': 2.0, '7': 1.0, '6': 1.0}`

I use:

```
it = iter(sorted(nums.items()))

try:
    while(True):
        print it.next()

except StopIteration:
    print "\n\n"
```

To print the elements ordered by key value but it doesn't work. I get

```
('10', 1.0)
('3', 1.6666666666666667)
('6', 1.0)
('7', 1.0)
```

which is not what I want. I also tried bunch of other stuff but those don't work as well.. any ideas ?

Comment: BTW, why don't you just loop over them with a for loop? It would be more compact than working with while, next, except...

Comment: My python knowledge is a bit rusty so just trying to get it work with whatever I remember since its just a simple script :) thanks for the advice though

Comment: It looks sorted to me. If you don't want it sorted in the default order, you have to specify how you want to sort it.

Comment: Cool- in the future, just do "for e in it: print e" (and if anyone  knows how to do the inline code backquote symbol on an iPad, please tell me!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is sorting the keys by their values as strings (that is, alphabetically- "1" comes before "3" comes before "6"...) rather than their integer value. If you want to sort the keys by their numerical value, you could do

```
iter(sorted(nums.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
```

Comment: Any ideas how can I make it sort by int value ?

Comment: @David Robinson.  Sorry for a basic question, I was just following this thread and tried to replicate the code, but I kept getting NameError: name 'nums' is not defined. Also, in the above code Cemre had dictionary named 'a', what does the 'x' do in this code? Much thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: @user1590499: `nums` is the dictionary to be sorted (Cemre called it `a` or `nums` alternatively but it makes no difference- you can make it `nums = {'10': 2.0, '3': 2.0, '7': 1.0, '6': 1.0}`. The `x` is an argument to the [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) `lambda x: int(x[0])`- you can read up on lambda functions to understand how that works.